# Is it possible to create a menu (content selection) using google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

Can we have a google maps in a page where we position pins and when the user clicks on a pin, to call a javascript, url or something so using Ajax to load content on another div etc

I am interested in the:

1. click on pin
2. call a jquery or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement *pins* by *markers*. A marker is created like this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({       
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(10.1, 20.2),       
    map: map     
    // ,icon: ..., etc.
});
```

Then you add event listeners to your markers:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
    // do here whatever you like 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can place any HTML in a marker that you want.

It'll be like any other piece of HTML on your page, so if you want to place a button or a link in there, and have it execute some script, you can do that.